# CirclePageIndicator bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I know this is quite common problem, but I couldn't find the answer to my question after googling for several hours.

I am using the PageViewIndicator library. I want to add circle indicators in the bottom of the layout. I am trying this , but when the app opens it crashes immediately. When I swap the places of  CirclePageIndicator and ViewPager it works perfectly but the indicator shows on the top of the activity .

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />


<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"

    />

   </LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I initialize it in Java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_test);

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

}
```

How can I fix this using only LinearLayout ?

Comment: try this  `com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator mIndicator = (com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);`

Comment: It's not working , as I mentioned above, when I change the places of pager and indicator , it works perfectly

Comment: What error/exception do you get when it crashes?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.TakeTestActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: I have just cleaned it and run again , but it still shows the same error message

Comment: you should set a static height for viewPager

Comment: I want it to resize depending on the height of the screen . How can I set it as a constant ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And since you don't want to show us your full activity (to see your field declaration) i'm guessing you're making something wrong since there is no way that this code will throw a cast exception:

```
FragmentAdapter adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);

CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
indicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

Comment: unfortunately it's crashing again , I have tried the same thing before

Comment: Then you will have to reformulate your question. `but when the app opens it crashes immediately` - `it works perfectly`. How does a app crashes when is opened and then works perfectly? Also show us the full activity, not just the onCreate

Comment: When I swap the places of CirclePageIndicator and ViewPager it works perfectly  - It means that when I write the layout file like this 
<LinearLayout>
<indicator/>
<pager/>
</LinearLayout>
It's working without errors. But I don't want the indicator to be on the top that's why I swap the pager and indicator and the application crashes in this case.

Comment: Make sure you pasted my code correctly. The error that you get is because you're casting the wrong ids to the wrong views.

Comment: If I'm casting them not correctly then why is it working without any errors when I change the order of views ? I think if the problem was in casting then it shouldn't have worked in both cases

Comment: `com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` You are trying to cast CirclePageIndicator to ViewPager...Try my XML. If it crashes tell me what is the error. Otherwise I can't help you anymore.

Comment: I pasted the same code you have posted above. I get the same error

Comment: I've updated my answer. If that doesn't help than I can't help you anymore and I suggest you reformulate your question so that others can help because, given the question as it is, this is as much help as you can get.

Comment: I have restarted my computer and device , and now it works fine. Thanks a lot